# CT showing different reading at phase and neutral

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, phasor, current-transformer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faQXCz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have attached a simplified version of my test circuit. When the current transformer is connected to the neutral side like in the diagram, it shows a significantly lower amount of current than the accurate one.

If I connect it to the phase, it shows the exact value. I have checked multiple times if there is any line going out of the bulb and found none. I used just one phase of a three-phase distribution line.

Answer (score 2):

If the CT is measuring a different current in a phase wire to the neutral wire, it's because **there is** a different current and, quite possibly that may be due to loads on the unspecified 2 other phases.

You could try a little experiment... put phase and neutral together through the CT. If it measures zero then I'm possibly wrong. My guess is that it produces a value equal to the difference you have seen.

Answer (score 0):

Was the "accurate one" also connected on neutral line? If not, then your CT measures the same as "accurate one" no matter where you place them, they will show the same.

The fact is that the neutral current in three phase system flows only if the load is asymmetric. If the load would be fully symmetric then zero amps would flow in the neutral conductor. It makes sense that the neutral current is smaller than phase current.

Comment: I understand that for a balanced three-phase system the neutral current will be zero. But if I use just one phase, then shouldn't the same phase current flow through the neural. The accurate one was taken from Hopi Power Meter. I didn't use any meter separately on neutral. I Can check that tomorrow in lab.